# Find out `thread group size` used in Metal fragment shader

Tags: ios, shader, metal, metalkit

In kernel shader we have to manually provide `thread group size`, like 4x4 or 16x32 etc, but fragment shader does calculate its `thread group size` (which I believe called `image block size` in fragment shader Metal terminology) implicitly to be what it thinks provide the best performance in particular case.

Is there a way to retrieve this automatically calculated `thread group/image block size` via Metal API? Or if it's not possible via API, maybe some clever fragment shader tricks could give a hint on what size used?

Comment: There's a `threads_per_threadgroup` attribute that you can apply on a parameter to a `kernel` function. For an image block, this is in general a dynamic value, so you are better off passing it as an input to a shader. Or you can create all your tile pipelines with `threadgroupSizeMatchesTileSize`, and then use threadgroup size.

Comment: @JustSomeGuy how can I pass `image block size` as an input if I don't know where to get it?

Comment: You can set `tileWidth` and `tileHeight` on an `MTLRenderPassDescriptor` or query it on an `MTLRenderCommandEncoder`.